# add text on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, x-editable

I´d like to know if someone can tell me why the added html in javascript is not working as the not added text.
meaning that if I add the text x-editable is not working. Following the scripts:

html:

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
   <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  </div>
    <p class="sm"><strong><a href="#" id='break1' data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="" >3 </a></strong><a href="#" id="break2" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-title="">&nbsp;NORMAL</a><span>TEXT</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

    if (counter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('p'))
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<p class="sm"><strong><a href="#" id="break3' + counter + '" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="" >3 </a></strong><a href="#" id="break4' + counter + '" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-title="">&nbsp;NORMAL</a><span>TEXT</span></p>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
  });
});
$(function () {
 $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
  $('#break1').editable();
  $('#break2').editable({
    prepend: "TEXT",
    placement: 'top',
    source: [{
        value: 1,
        text: 'TEXT1'
    }, {
        value: 2,
        text: 'TEXT2'
    }],

});
  $('#break32').editable();
  $('#break42').editable({
    prepend: "TEXT",
    placement: 'top',
    source: [{
        value: 1,
        text: 'TEXT1'
    }, {
        value: 2,
        text: 'TEXT2'
    }],

 });

 });
```

or:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5yyLb9b/2/)

Comment: Well.. it looks like you would have duplicate IDs if you add the HTML to the document. Two elements with the same ID won't work as is invalid. Also.. maybe `.editable` needs to be delegated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making generated elements editable.

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5yyLb9b/5/)

On the click of button you are creating controls but not making them editable as you did for your first set of controls.

Make them editable as you create them.

Check following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('p'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<p class="sm"><strong><a href="#" id="break3' + counter + '" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="" >3 </a></strong><a href="#" id="break4' + counter + '" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-title="">&nbsp;NORMAL</a><span>TEXT</span></p>');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

 $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $('#break3'+counter).editable();
    $('#break4'+counter).editable({
        prepend: "TEXT",
        placement: 'top',
        source: [{
            value: 1,
            text: 'TEXT1'
        }, {
            value: 2,
            text: 'TEXT2'
        }],

    });



        counter++;
    });
});
$(function () {

 $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $('#break1').editable();
    $('#break2').editable({
        prepend: "TEXT",
        placement: 'top',
        source: [{
            value: 1,
            text: 'TEXT1'
        }, {
            value: 2,
            text: 'TEXT2'
        }],

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
$($(newTextBoxDiv).find("a")[0]).editable();
$($(newTextBoxDiv).find("a")[1]).editable({
   prepend: "TEXT",
   placement: 'top',
   source: [{
       value: 1,
       text: 'TEXT1'
   }, {
       value: 2,
       text: 'TEXT2'
   }],
```

});

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5yyLb9b/3/)

Your code runs once when your page loads, therefore it makes the available fields you specified editable.

But when new fields are generated during run-time, no codes have been executed for them to make them editable.

Therefore I added the above code to make the fields editable right after then are generated.